# Как быстро получить сочетания 2 из n элементов в порядке возрастания их суммы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Есть возрастающий вектор из n элементов >= 1. Требуется найти следующее сочетание из 2 элементов с минимальной их суммой за O(1) или за O(log n), зная предыдущее.

Например для вектора {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
это будут сочетания {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 4} и т.д.

Какой алгоритм для этого использовать?

Comment: Если хранить статус размера *O(N)*, то можно переходить к следующему сочетанию за  *O(logN)*. Это хуже чем вы просите. Сойдёт?

Comment: Что-то заставляет меня думать что если дана только пара элементов, следующую пару быстрее чем за *O(N)* вы не найдёте. Можно попробовать привести пример в котором если вы не проверили все элементы будет ошибка - следующая пара будет не минимальной. Да, так и есть, я придумал пример.

Comment: В общем, или вы разрешаете строить специальную поисковую структуру или платите линейное время за поиск следующей пары без подготовки.

Comment: Минусаторы, объяснитесь. Задача крайне не простая.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, хранить статус можно, преподсчет за его N тоже, главное в итоге каждый запрос за O(logN) отвечать

Comment: а почему (1, 4) идет после (2,3) и (1,5) после (2,4), когда (2,5) перед (3,4) ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, предположу что пары с одинаковой суммой упорядочены лексикографически, то есть по первому элементу.

Comment: Запрос запросу рознь. Если вам нужно перебрать все сочетания последовательно - одно. Если вы хотите по любой паре выдать следующую - другое. Первое или второе? Или что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идейно этот ответ повторяет [ответ MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1536036/416121): приоритетная очередь с парами индексов. Размер очереди *N*, время инициализации *N*, время выдачи следующей пары *log N*. Общее время работы *N·log N*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

void print_pairs(const std::vector<int> &v) {
    using pair = std::pair<size_t, size_t>;

    const auto sum = [&v](const pair &p) {
        return v[p.first] + v[p.second];
    };

    const auto key = [sum](const pair &p) {
        return std::make_pair(sum(p), p.first);
    };

    const auto cmp = [key](const pair &p1, const pair &p2) {
        return key(p2) < key(p1);
    };

    std::priority_queue<pair, std::vector<pair>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i) {
        q.push({i, i + 1});
    }
    while (!q.empty()) {
        const pair p = q.top();
        q.pop();
        std::cout <<
            sum(p) << " = " << v[p.first] << " + " << v[p.second] << '\n';
        if (p.second < v.size() - 1) {
            q.push({p.first, p.second + 1});
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    print_pairs({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Выложу перебор сочетаний по возрастанию сумм на Python.

Суть такая - в очередь по приоритетам кладём кортежи из суммы соседних элементов, индекса левого и правого. Сравнение происходит по первичному ключу - сумме, а вторичный ключ - левый индекс, что обеспечивает лексикографическое упорядочение.

Первичная закладка в кучу всех левых элементов и сдвиг правых только вправо приводит к тому, что не нужно отслеживать повторы. Размер кучи O(N).

Извлекаем минимальный кортеж из кучи, выводим, сдвигаем правый индекс вправо, обновляем сумму, и вставляем кортеж обратно. Переход к следующему сочетанию - O(logN)

```
import random, bisect, heapq
n = 6
#a = random.sample(range(1,21), k=n)
#a.sort()
a = [1,2,4,5,6,9]
print(a)

hp = []
for i in range(n-1):
    hp.append((a[i]+a[i+1], i, i+1))
heapq.heapify(hp)
while hp:
    s,l,r = heapq.heappop(hp)
    print(s,l,r,a[l],a[r])
    if r < n-1:
        heapq.heappush(hp, (a[l]+a[r+1],l,r+1))

[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9]
3 0 1 1 2
5 0 2 1 4
6 0 3 1 5
6 1 2 2 4
7 0 4 1 6
7 1 3 2 5
8 1 4 2 6
9 2 3 4 5
10 0 5 1 9
10 2 4 4 6
11 1 5 2 9
11 3 4 5 6
13 2 5 4 9
14 3 5 5 9
15 4 5 6 9
```

P.S. Задачу "по одной паре получить следующую" попробовал решить с дополнительным массивом "cледующая сумма для данного левого индекса" и поиском левого по этому массиву, а правого по исходному, однако обновление доп. массива должно идти постоянно с начала перечисления, так что тупик.

Comment: Для генерации пар в нужном порядке - отличное решение.